# Pagesize and number of records are not matching - angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I am using ngb pagination of angular6, there in API given scenario totalCount is 45 and on every page change until 5th page it sends pageSize=10 and it works great. However, for 5th page it sends pageSize=5 and pager in HTML shows 21-30 which is incorrect and it should show as 41-45 data. if anybody can help on this please.

in my HTML Component :

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
                <p><small>{{startIndex}}-{{endIndex}} of over {{totalCount}} results for data</small></p>
            </div>
      <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="totalCount" [page]="p"
                                (pageChange)="showAllData($event)" [maxSize]="3" [rotate]="true" [ellipses]="false">
                            </ngb-pagination>
```

in ts file it is I have clode as below.

```
 showAllData(page: number) {     
            this.myservice.getAlldata(this.showAllUrl, page, this.selectedInputfield).subscribe(response => {
              this.content = response;
              this.pageSize = +response.pager.pageSize
              this.totalCount = response.pager.totalCount;
              if (page == 1  ) {
                this.startIndex =1;
                this.endIndex = page  *  this.pageSize;
              }
              else {
                this.startIndex = (( page - 1 ) * this.pageSize) +  1
                this.endIndex = (this.startIndex -1)  + (this.pageSize);
              }   

            },
            (error) => { 

                }
            )
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using pageSize to calculate the starting index of the currently shown page:

```
this.startIndex = (( page - 1 ) * this.pageSize) +  1
```

and if you do not have a fixed maximum page size (eg. show at most 10 items per page) you can't calculate the starting index. If you have a fixed max page size you could calculate start and end index like this:

```
this.startIndex = (( page - 1 ) * maxItemsPerPage) +  1
this.endIndex = (this.startIndex -1)  + (this.pageSize);
```

Comment: thanks for your input, but that is how I have to deal with, the pageSize could vary, depends upon what API gives.

Comment: @hdc if the backend returns you a smaller page size only for the last page then you can assume that it is showing indexes from totalSize - pageSize to totalSize, and use the existing code to calculate indexes if pageSize is the same as in other calls